# Background video comparison on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a video comparison header for a site I'm building. I have two videos on top of one another, and I'm trying to create a comparison slider effect where the top layer reveals the bottom on mouse position.

Fiddle/code below, any help would be much appreciated.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0a28kj07/)

HTML:

```
<video class="one" loop autoplay poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/dirty.jpg">
    <source src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/floodplain-dirty.mp4>
    <source src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/floodplain-dirty.webm>
  </video>
    <video class="two" loop autoplay poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/clean.jpg">
      <source src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/floodplain-clean.mp4>
      <source src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/floodplain-clean.webm>
    </video>
```

CSS:

```
video {
  position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to display as full page?

Comment: If possible. Plan was to display in full viewport and add content below to scroll to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a [bin](http://jsbin.com/zotirarode/edit?output). It's not exactly as your described not sure this is acceptable to you?

The idea not much different from your codepen example. The second video will clipped by a clipper element.

```
<div class="box" id="box">
  <video>...</video>      
  <div class="clipper" id="clipper">
    <video>...</video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Set the clipper to absolute position.

```
.clipper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

On `mousemove` event change bottom position.

```
<script>
  box.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    var top = box.offsetTop
    var height = box.offsetHeight
    var y = event.pageY
    clipper.style.bottom = Math.max(top + height - y, 0) + 'px'
  })
</script>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented, but I don't have enough reputation, yet. (Sorry)

If you want to have a complete reveal, then you could add a range slider with a change event listener and adjust the opacity of the top layer video according to the value of the range slider.

Comment: No worries! That'd be a good alternative. Was hoping to achieve an effect similar to this though: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/EIKzk

Comment: So, you found your answer. Or is there a reason, why you can't use the code from the link?

Comment: The code is great, but I was hoping to get both videos to fill 100% view height/width. Haven't been able to figure it out